# Superscalar processors and complex instructions

Tags: computer-architecture, parallel-computing, concurrency

I read that a supercalar processor has redundant functional units. One can read this e.g. on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar).

How do such redundant units work?

Is a complex instruction (for accelerating heavy process, for example Instructions used in Intel IPP, Integrated Performance Primitives) decomposed in micro operations befaure being dispatched among these redudant functional units?

What about hardware instructions? Like AES-NI?

I also read the [Wikipedia article SMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) and did not understand the following sentence:

> Superscalar means executing multiple instructions at the same time while thread-level parallelism (TLP) executes instructions from multiple threads within one processor chip at the same time.

I don't understand very well the distinction between these two things. Can somebody explain the subtleties?

Comment: It is not the case that superscalar processors have "redundant" functional units.  Some (not all) have several functional units that are capable of performing the same function at the same time.

Comment: I provide a link where we can read that. I also read that on slides about computer architecture...

Comment: The wikipedia page is wrong.  They use the term "redundant" where they mean "more than one."

Comment: We can read the same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656608/what-is-difference-between-superscaling-and-pipelining

Comment: @Wandering Logic "They use the term "redundant" where they mean "more than one." The meaning is the same, more than one means $\ge 2$.

Comment: No.  Google the definition of "redundant."  It means "not or no longer needed or useful; superfluous," or "not strictly necessary to functioning but included in case of failure in another component".

Comment: A superscalar processor has more than one functional unit.  But the functional units may perform different functions.  For example, often there is an arithmetic unit, a memory unit and a branching unit.  You can't do a division operation with a memory unit, but the processor can simultaneously execute a division operation and a memory load operation.

Comment: Thanks @WanderingLogic For this term, I don't think it's important to interpret it in such or another manner, provided that doesn't lead to other misunderstanting. It's not completely incorrect to consider these functional units as "superfluous", since sometimes the redundant ones are not used, especially for purely sequential programs...

Comment: It leads to misunderstanding.  Superscalar does _not_ mean that the functional units can perform the same instruction or operation.  There is _nothing_ superfluous or redundant between a branching unit and an arithmetic unit and a memory unit.

Comment: I've fixed the wikipedia page.

Comment: You are asking multiple things at once. Please restrict your post to a single question!

Comment: @WanderingLogic Look at the first diagram in the Wiki page. We can have two times an EX and two times a MEM. "Superscalar does not mean that the functional units can perform the same instruction or operation" Is this remark really related to my question ? The instructions executed could be the same or different, I think that does not matter... "There is nothing superfluous or redundant between a branching unit and an arithmetic unit and a memory unit." Yes I understand, but the term redundant here is used when we have two times the same functional unit...

Comment: I would like such questions asked in Computer Engeneering site. Computer Engeneering is a speciality adjacent to Computer Science. "Computer Science is about computers as much as astronomy is about telescopes". Please keep that in mind and create a computer engeneering se department.

Comment: @Val At least two Area51 attempts to start a Computer Architecture SE failed for lack of interest (not even passing the definition phase for the second attempt). CE (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_engineering)) adds software and lower and higher levels of hardware, but s/w folks might prefer not to mix with h/w folks and EE SE can cover most hardware questions. This is also related to the [fragmentation issue WL brought up on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177783/226495).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton I see how they "not prefer". Raphael regularly invites telescope builders at this CS site. The result of this kind of struggling with framgentation, the Computer Engeneering/Architecture questions are fragmented all over CS/StackOverflow and EE sites. Fragmentation is a bad way to combat against it. I make my note just because I feel sad that Computer Engeneers have no their site and have to host and fragmented everywhere, as poor relatives.

Answer (score 2):

You should understand that any program is a sequence of instructions (ok, you an think of it as a collection of threads, where every thread is a sequence of instructions or a virtual process that executes that series of instructions). The instructions are supposed to be executed one after another. Single pipeline processor fetches instruction as they are ought to, every clock cycle and keeps its functional unit executing an instruction per cycle. This is not very true actually because execution takes multiple cycles and you fetch next instruction before previous is complete. But we pretend that instructions are still executed one after another and you still need one FU. Superscalars, however, cheat. They tell to the user that they still execute her program as designed, one instruction after another, yet take a window of neighbor instructions and execute them at once. They introduce extra FUs (Wikipedia called them "redundant") for this technique, called "Instruction Level Parallelism" (ILP).

Superscalars also have to entail a complex [dependency detection and maintenance mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dependency). As [Amdahl has explained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)), because instructions of the same thread operate on the same data set, you have a lot of dependencies, especially among neighbor instructions and, thus cannot gain a lot of parallelism at ILP. The parallel pipelines are therefore sometimes used to execute different threads. This is full-scale parallelism already (except the synchronization cases and cache contention, which prevents any advantage of TLP over ILP, especially if von Neumann bottleneck is considered). Such TLP is known as *hyperthreading*. Yet, it is true parallelism since now threads are indeed executed in parallel, as if there are multiple cores, rather than parallelism is emulated by periodically switching threads on a single pipeline and, therefore, is also called "simultaneous multithreading".

I do not even see any reason to differentiate between multicore and hyperthreading. Since different pipelines execute different threads, this means that they have separate instruction pointer, set of registers and everything you need for the context, which are switched. Might be the common cache and shared FUs is the only things that distinguishes single core from multiple cores. Yes, shared cache. This may save you from cache incoherence /memory consistence problems that can happen in truly multicore system.

Comment: Thanks but I am sceptic. You write "I do not even see any reason to differentiate between multicore and hyperthreading". Really ?? In general applications have only a small gain by using hyperthreading, so I'm wondering if instructions belonging to one thread can be dispatched in redundant functional units... This would coincide with the general low gain of hyperthreading.

Comment: "Since different pipelines execute different threads, this means that they have separate instruction pointer, set of registers and everything you need for the context, which are switched." I've seen this post http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11426/parallel-computing-past-vs-present/11432#11432

Comment: That post is about multicores. Multicores share main memory and large slow cache, eg. L3 or something. Reduntant FUs are exactly for different pipelines could use them. I do not see how redundancy of FUs can slow down your system. The data flow dependency among instructions certainly does.

Comment: I don't undserstand and I think we make a complete digression. My question is about a citation from Wiki, which lask of details. For instance "within one processor chip at the same time" is not sufficiently accurate for me...

Comment: "Superscalar" stands for multiple instructions at once by the parallel pipelines of same core. It either means ILP or TLP. You can also do TLP employing multi(core)processor within single chip or even distribute it over several chips. You cannot distribute ILP over multiple chips (well, you can but it would not worth the effect).

Comment: Thanks, your comment helps me a lot. Can you say me if the followings are correct: 1) Thread-level parallelism refers to the execution of multiple thread on a same core (possibly using SMT) or on several cores. 2) Thread-level parallelism=multithreading ?

Comment: The first is right but multithreading is a programming concept. It has first appeared in a singlecore (and I believe non-superscalar) processors. There was a single processor in old systems but programmers neverless wanted to create impression that several things are executed simultaneously. OS started to expose concept of multiple threads. OS knew when another thread started a long (means IO) operation and switched processor to execute another thread or did switch a thread (preemptively) after a certain amount of CPU time. This was emulated multithreading. TLP is *true* multithreading!

Comment: @Val: "single processor in old systems" - you might want to check back. System/360 is ancient, yet supported 2 processors since model 65 which coincidentally shipped in 1965. Switching processors to execute another thread is even older, as you switch threads when switching between processes. Multiple threads per process came quite a bit later.

Comment: @MSalters Are you objecting to anything?

Comment: @Val: Yes, primarily your claim that multi-threading appeared in a single processor system where programmers wanted to create the impression of multiple things executing simultaneously. The System/360 history suggests otherwise. Which computer were you thinking of?

Comment: @MSalters Obviously, I was talking about mainstream (Wintel) platform. It is sufficient to demonstrate my primary point that you may have multithreading without TLP, which is sufficient to demonstrate that multithreadint != TLP. That was the question and my intent. Secondly, I do not see what IBM demonstrates here. Ok, IBM had multiprocessors ages before Wintel single processor. And what? It does not even object the statement "multithreading appeared in single processors first".

Comment: The fact that you build supercomputers (where term CPU does not matter at all) since 1965 does not eliminate the natural possibility that you started with single processor + multithreading even before that nor it eliminates the possibility that some another company started the natural path of multicomputing from a single pipeline a bit later. So, I do not see how your enciclopedic knowledge helps to understand that multithreading is not TLP and can exist without it.